Group rows of data in a multidimensional array by a column and merge subarrays in another column
I am trying to group the data in my 3d array by one column value (order_id) and merge the subarray values in the products column within each group.
Sample data:
$ordersGlobal = [
    [
        "order_id" => "65", 
        "products" => [
           [
              "description" => "Test6", 
              "brand" => "ACL", 
              "code" => "303127005576", 
              "OriginalPrice" => "328.0000"
           ] 
        ] 
    ], 
    [
        "order_id" => "66",  
        "products" => [
            [
                "description" => "Test5", 
                "brand" => "TEA", 
                "code" => "3900055", 
                "OriginalPrice" => "43.0000" 
            ] 
        ] 
    ], 
    [
        "order_id" => "66",
        "products" => [
            [
                "description" => "Te3st4", 
                "brand" => "TEA", 
                "code" => "3900056", 
                "OriginalPrice" => "43.0000"
            ] 
        ] 
    ]
] 

Desired result:
[
    [
        "order_id" => "65", 
        "products" => [
           [
              "description" => "Test6", 
              "brand" => "ACL", 
              "code" => "303127005576", 
              "OriginalPrice" => "328.0000"
           ] 
        ] 
    ], 
    [
        "order_id" => "66",  
        "products" => [
            [
                "description" => "Test5", 
                "brand" => "TEA", 
                "code" => "3900055", 
                "OriginalPrice" => "43.0000" 
            ],
            [
                "description" => "Te3st4", 
                "brand" => "TEA", 
                "code" => "3900056", 
                "OriginalPrice" => "43.0000"
            ] 

        ] 
    ]
]

My coding attempt:
$order_merge = array();
foreach ($ordersGlobal as $k => $data) {
    $orderId1 = $data['order_id'];
    $orderId2 = next($ordersGlobal)['order_id'] ?? false;
    if ($orderId1 == $orderId2) {
        $order_merge[$k]['order_id'] = $data['order_id'];
        $order_merge[$k]['products'] = array_merge(
            next($ordersGlobal)['products'],
            $data['products']
        );
    } else {
        $order_merge[$k]['order_id'] = $data['order_id'];
        // $order_merge[$k]['customerId'] = 1 $order_merge[$k]['products'] = $data['products'];
    }
} 


Hi, can you share your actual code please

I did this ($ordersGlobal is the name of array) :  $order_merge = array();   foreach ($ordersGlobal  as $k =>  $data) {  $orderId1 = $data['order_id'];
$orderId2 = next($ordersGlobal)['order_id'] ?? false;
if($orderId1 == $orderId2){
$order_merge[$k]['order_id'] = $data['order_id'];
    $order_merge[$k]['products'] = array_merge(next($ordersGlobal)['products'], $data['products']);

}else{
$order_merge[$k]['order_id'] = $data['order_id'];
//   $order_merge[$k]['customerId'] = 1
$order_merge[$k]['products'] = $data['products'];
}}

I think it should works
$productsTemp = [];
$ordersMerge = [];

foreach ($ordersGlobal as $actualOrder)
{
    if (key_exists($actualOrder["order_id"], $productsTemp))
    {
        array_push($productsTemp[$actualOrder["order_id"]]["products"], $actualOrder["products"][0]);
    }
    else
    {
        $productsTemp[$actualOrder["order_id"]]["products"] = $actualOrder["products"];
    }
}

$ordersMerge[] = $productsTemp;


Thank you for this help. It's almost work. But for arrays that have the same  order_id like 66, I got arrays inside the array for the second element "products".

Hi ! You need an array inside products ?

No,  the result is like this: [66] =>
[
[products] =>[
[
[0] => Array
[
]
                        [1] => [
                                [0] => Array
                                    [
                                       data  here ...
                                    ]                ]          ]


I want it to be like this: : [66] => [ [products] =>[ [ [0] => Array [ data ....... ] [1] => [ [ data ... ] ] ]

The fisrt array for every "products" key is fine but the second array is an array inside array.

I think it will be good, replace :
$productsTemp[$actualOrder["order_id"]]["products"][] = $actualOrder["products"];
by
array_push($productsTemp[$actualOrder["order_id"]]["products"], $actualOrder["products"][0]);
Tell me if is good ;)

@ali i've updated the post too ;)

thank you so much @ZbobModel.php. I'm getting the right result. So grateful.

This unexplained answer DOES perform "grouping" but it also destroys the original 2-column structure. Proof: https://3v4l.org/4eFJX

Here's a clean approach to push unique references into a result array and append  one or more products values into the group's subarray.
Code: (Demo)
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['order_id']])) {
        $ref[$row['order_id']] = $row;
        $result[] = &$ref[$row['order_id']];
    } else {
        array_push($ref[$row['order_id']]['products'], ...$row['products']);
    }
}
var_export($result);

